# How To Set Versions in Xcode 13?

Tags: xcode

Whenever I changed the settings, after I switched to other page and switched back, the setting was restored. Nothing I changed was kept.

[image]

Comment: You need to tab out of the field in order to make the update. Did you definitely tab out of the field (or click on another field). Without doing that it won’t have taken a new value.

Comment: You can create a SwiftUI app and try it yourself. For me, the info part would be restored to default each time.